# finding a plane that forms an acute angle $\theta/2$ with two planes that have $\theta$ as angle between them

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, plane-geometry

> Let $\theta$ denote the angle between the planes $2x+2y+z = 1$ and $-x + 2y - 2z = 2$. The planes intersect in a line that we call L. Find the plane that contains L and forms acute angle $\theta/2$ with both planes.

First of all, $n_1 = <2, 2, 1>$ and $n_2 = <-1, 2, -2>$. Then $\cos \theta$ gives that $\theta = 90°$, using the dot product.Thus the angle the plane in question forms with the two planes would be $45°$ each.

I'm unsure about what to do next, however. Let $n_3$ be the normal to the plane the problem asks for—plane 3. Depending on how I draw the 3 planes, it seems that I could either get $n_3 = n_2 - n_1$ (or $n_3 = n_1 - n_2$; the key is $n_3$ is the difference of the normals of two given planes) or $n_3 = n_1 + n_2$. And computing in these two different ways give different planes. Which one would I know is the correct approach (without using any of the graphing calculators etc.)?

Or would both planes be accepted as the answer, since in this case $\theta = 90°$? What if $\theta$ was an acute or obtuse angle, however? How would my problem-solving approach change, to still get the plane that contains L and forms $\theta/2$ (acute) angle with the two planes?

Comment: The equation of a plane passing through the intersection of two planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ is given by $P_1+\lambda P_2=0$. Now, use the fact that it makes an angle of $45°$ with the other planes to find $\lambda$.

Comment: @SarGe—I've never seen that formula ($P_1 + \lambda P_2 = 0$ before)—is that a pretty well-known theorem?

Comment: -@space, since the normal vector of all the three planes are coplanar, we can write one of them in linear combination of the other two.

Comment: -@space, did you get the answer?